# Plot MiniBatchKMeans, how to get different colors for different clusters

Tags: python, matplotlib, cluster-analysis, k-means, scatter-plot

I collected a lot of words and put them into a file. Next I put them through a gensim word2vec model. Then I performed a MiniBatchKMeans.
So far so good and the results are really nice.

Now I want to plot the clusters in a scatter diagram. I have seen really cool pictures how it should work.
My idea is to get a scatter plot where you can see all the words and all the clusters (with the same color).

Alright, so far so good.

I have found some code online and changed it a little bit.
The loop after "Kleuren = []" is to get random colors, same amount as the amount of clusters I have.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 8))
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.04, right=0.98, bottom=0.1, top=0.9)
kleuren = []
for color in cycle(colors.cnames.keys()):
    kleuren.append(color)
    if len(kleuren) == n_clusters:
        break

t_mini_batch = time.time() - t0

# MiniBatchKMeans
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 3, 1)

for this_centroid, k, col in zip(classifier.cluster_centers_, range(n_clusters), kleuren):
    mask = classifier.labels_ == k
    ax.scatter(x[mask, 0], x[mask, 1], marker='.', c=kleuren, edgecolor=col, alpha=0.5)
    ax.scatter(this_centroid[0], this_centroid[1], marker='+', c='k', s=50)
ax.set_xticks(())
ax.set_yticks(())
ax.set_title("MiniBatchKMeans")
ax.set_autoscaley_on(False)
plt.text(-3.5, 1.8, 'train time: %.2fs\ninertia: %f' %(t_mini_batch, classifier.inertia_))

plt.show()
```

To get to this point, I have to get the MinibatchKMeans (classifier) and the x.

```
dictFileName = "D:\PYTHON\WordVec/wiki.nl.vec.bin"
KeywordFile="D:\PYTHON\DataFiles/dsh_corsa_keywords_question.txt"

model = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(dictFileName, binary=True)

# read keywords from CLEAN source file
words = []
for line in open(KeywordFile,'r'):
    words.append(line.split(';')[0])

NumOfWords = len(words)

x = np.zeros((NumOfWords, model.vector_size)) for i in range(0, NumOfWords):
    x[i,]=model[words[i]] 

# Generate sample data
np.random.seed(0)

# Generate centers for the blobs so that it forms a 10 X 10 grid.
xx = np.linspace(-22, 22, 10)
yy = np.linspace(-22, 22, 10)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(xx, yy)
centers = np.hstack((np.ravel(xx)[:, np.newaxis], np.ravel(yy)[:, np.newaxis]))
n_clusters = 100

t0 = time.time()
classifier = MiniBatchKMeans(n_clusters=n_clusters, batch_size=100, verbose=0, random_state=0, init_size = 500, n_init=20, max_iter=1000)
classifier.fit(x)
```

Alright, if I run all of this I get a scatterplot with a lot of dots and a lot of colors but no clusters at all.

There are some parts code where I'm not totally sure if I really understand what's happening and how that's affecting the result.
First of all, I use x in the scatter to get all the points. X is a list of all the vectors.
Is it possible, the words in x are sorted in a different way and that's what causes this random plot?

Next, the centers. I have a random grid to start from and the KMeans will changes those centers until it's done. So I think this won't give any problems.

And last, I have a list of all colors and I'm not sure if this is how it should be.

Alright, long story but I could really use some help here, some guidance into the right direction or some tips.
Especially the for loop in the scatter. I understand what it does but I have the feeling I don't get it really.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your vectors probably have 100 dimensions, so I am not surprised you don't see much in the first two dimensions only...

Comment: Okay, is there a way to plot those vectors in a 2 dimensions plot?

Comment: Not without loss. But there are various projection techniques.